handling subtracting bills and coins in a vending machine system
I need to handle each entry based on the test cases file, the only test case i am having a trouble with is the test case which requires to subtract a 1 bill from a 10 bill which is only possible if the first entry before subtraction have a 1 bill in its composition.
in other words the system should track money not as just a sum but as bills and coins as well, when a customer requests to buy an item and enters the money that he has, i need to make sure that change can be returned.
For example, if we have a 10 Dollars bill, and someone is asking for 5 Dollars in return, you cannot return the money, but if you have 10 one dollar bills you can return five one dollar bills.
here is my code
public class Money {

    private final double amount;

    public static final Money Zero = new Money(0.00);
    public static final Money OneCent = new Money(0.01);
    public static final Money FiveCent = new Money(0.05);
    public static final Money TenCent = new Money(0.10);
    public static final Money TwentyFiveCent = new Money(0.25);
    public static final Money FiftyCent = new Money(0.50);
    public static final Money OneDollar = new Money(1.00);
    public static final Money FiveDollar = new Money(5.00);
    public static final Money TenDollar = new Money(10.00);
    public static final Money TwentyDollar = new Money(20.00);
    public static final Money FiftyDollar = new Money(50.00);




    //custom constructor to handle instantiating objects & handling input violations.
    public Money(double amount) {
        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Amount cannot be negative");
        }
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public double amount() {

        return amount;
    }

    //multiplies the amount by a given count.
    public Money times(int count) {
        if (count < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Count cannot be negative");
        }

        return new Money(this.amount * count);
    }


    //adds the amount of another Money object to the current one.
    public Money plus(Money other) {
        return new Money(this.amount + other.amount);
    }

    //subtracts the amount of another Money object, with a check to prevent negative results.
    public Money minus(Money other) {

        if (this.amount < other.amount) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot subtract more than the available amount");
        }
        double result =this.amount-other.amount;
        System.out.println(" this " + this.amount +" minus "+other.amount+" IS "+result);
    return new Money(result);
    }

}

and here is the test cases
@Test
    public void minusTest() {
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> Zero.minus(OneDollar));
        assertEquals(Zero, Zero.minus(Zero));
        assertEquals(Zero, OnePiaster.minus(OnePiaster));
        assertEquals(OneDollar, FiveDollar.plus(OneDollar).minus(FiveDollar));
        assertEquals(FiveDollar, OneDollar.times(10).minus(FiveDollar));
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> TenDollar.minus(OneDollar));
        
    }

all tests pass except the last one. How would I compare this equals 9?

is your test subtracting one from ten, or ten from one? There is nothing in your code that tracks any sort of composition. all it does it manipulate the amount

one from ten, i don't need to track them literally, for example there is a test case that does a 5 dollars plus 1 dollar then subtracts five dollars so we end up with 1, but the code should only allow that in case the initial value (in this case 5 plus 1) composition has that bill in it.

Then why do you expect the IllegalArgumentException to be thrown? your only check is that this value cannot be smaller than the other value / end result cannot be negative and 10 - 1 is not negative

i know, but i cannot figure a way to check if the result (which is 9 in the last test case) is composed of which bills to handle it properly. im new to programming so i don't know what to do honestly.

i had a thought to implement a hash set to store the bill composition for each entry, but the same problem, i don't know how.

why would you need to implement your own hashset? also, what you are looking for is a hashmap (just import it from Java's standard library) which allows key value pairs i.e. {Money(10)=1,Money(5)=2} which would sum up to 20

And if that was your problem you should have mentioned it instead of not mentioning the problem at all, and just saying the issue was that the last test case is not passing

sorry for that, it is indeed my bad that i didn't phrase the problem correctly, due to my little knowledge and understanding.

Don't worry too much about it, now you can try to implement the composition part using a hashmap, then if you have any problems in the implementation you can come back and ask again

ok, i'll try that, tyvm for the advice.

oh btw, if you were to for example implement a wallet class that would store the composition, it would be better from a logical perspective to move the methods times(), plus() and minus() from the money class to the wallet (and reimplement it based on the composition), because money cant add itself or minus itself, but you can add or minus from your wallet. Just something to consider.

You'll need to implement equals and hashcode functions, by the way. It's not clear how the equality tests are passing without at least the equals method implemented

Your test fails because 10-1 is a valid expression.
Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but the left side of the equality doesn't need to be a fixed value, so compare appropriately.
assertEquals(OneDollar.times(9), TenDollar.minus(OneDollar)))    
assertEquals(FiveDollar.plus(OneDollar.times(4)), TenDollar.minus(OneDollar)))


the system should track money not as just a sum but as bills and coins as well

You'll need a different data structure for this, such as Map<Money, Integer>
